# Expose Component Method in React

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I'm having an issue updating a value in React.

I have a component that increments and decrements a value when clicked.  This part works as it should but the issue I am having is exposing that to another part of another component so that it corresponds with the sum of the numbers.

Basically I have a quantity that needs to be updated and there is a count that shows the total number of selections.  Also note that this updates a dollar amount as well.  For instance one price would be $10 and if I choose 5 then the total number would be 5 and price would be $50.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Quantity Component:

```
import React from 'react';
import If from '../utils/helpers';


var QuantityInput = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      quantity: 0
    };
  },

  handleIncrement: function(e) {
    this.props.handleIncrement(this.props.quantity + 1);
  },

  handleDecrement: function(e) {
    if (this.props.quantity > 1) {
      this.props.handleDecrement(this.props.quantity - 1);
    }
  },

  handleChange: function(e) {
    var value = e.target.value.replace(/[^0-9]/, '');

    value = (value == '' ? 1 : value);
    value = parseInt(value);

    this.setState({
      quantity: value
    });
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="quantity-input">
        <span className="button button--gray controls__quantity" onClick={this.handleDecrement}>-</span>
        <div className="quantity" onChange={this.handleChange}>{this.state.quantity}</div>
        <span className="button button--gray controls__quantity" onClick={this.handleIncrement}>+</span>
      </div>
    );
  }
});

module.exports = QuantityInput;
```

Products:

```
import React from 'react';
import If from '../utils/helpers';
import QuantityInput from '../components/quantity.js'


var Product = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      quantity: 0
    }
  },

  handleIncrement: function(e) {
    this.setState({
      quantity: this.state.quantity + 1
    });
  },

  handleDecrement: function(e) {
    if (this.state.quantity > 1) {
      this.setState({
        quantity: this.state.quantity - 1
      });
    }
  },

  render: function() {
    var content;
    if (this.props.items.length > 0) {
      this.props.items.map(function(product) {
        var items = product.priceCode.map(function(priceCode) {
          return (
            <div className="list-item" key={priceCode.priceCode_id}>
              <div className="list-info list-info--cart">
                <div className="list-info__venue">
                  <h3 className="event-title">{priceCode.priceCode_title}</h3>
                  <If condition={priceCode.priceCode_passcode}>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Passcode" />
                  </If>
                  <span className="event-details">{priceCode.priceCode_info}</span>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="controls">
                <div className="list-info__price">${priceCode.priceCode_price}</div>
                <QuantityInput />
              </div>
            </div>
          )
        });

        content = {items}
      });
    }

    return (
      <div>
        {content}
      </div>
    );
  }
});

var ProductContainer = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      data: [],
      quantity: 0
    }
  },

  componentWillMount: function() {
    this.loadProducts(this.props.url);
  },

  loadProducts: function(url) {
    $.ajax({
      url: url,
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data) {
        this.setState({
          data: data
        });
      }.bind(this),
      error: function(xhr, status, err, data) {
        console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
      }.bind(this)
    });
  },

  _hasData: function() {
    var displayedItems = this.state.data.filter(function(product) {
      var match = product.priceCode.filter(function(priceCode) {
        return priceCode.priceCode_title.toLowerCase();
      });

      return (match !== -1);
    }.bind(this));

    return (
      <div>
        <Product items={displayedItems} />
      </div>
    ); 
  }, 

  render: function() {
    if (this.state.data) {
      return (
        <div className="price-code">
          {this._hasData()}
          <div className="subtotal-wrapper">
            <a href="#" className="button button--gray">Clear Selections</a>
            <div className="subtotal">
              Subtotal ({this.state.quantity}):
            </div>
            <a href="#" className="button">Find Tickets</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      )          
    } else {
      return <div>Loading...</div>;
    }

    return false
  }
});

module.exports = ProductContainer;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In React, it's best to have the data flow "downstream" within your app. I would advise putting the quantity as a state attribute in the `Product` component, then define the increment/decrement functions in that same componet. The `QuantityInput` would receive those functions as props and call them when the onClicks are fired.

Here's an example for one of the handlers (called in the `QuanityInput`)...

```
handleIncrement: function(e) {
  this.props.handleIncrement(this.props.quantity + 1);
},
```

This allows you to manipule the state on the actual product, as oposed to keeping in locked in the child component. You can always look into `refs`, but that's not really a best practice for getting the state.

EDIT:
Just like 'primative' props, you just pass them into the child component like this:

```
<QuantityInput handleIncrement={this.handleIncrement} handleDecrement={this.handleDecrement}/>
```

Comment: Sorry but I'm a complete noob at React.  I've what you suggested but I am getting errors `this.props.handleIncrement is not a function`.  I've edited my code so you can see what I have now.

Comment: No worries! I updated my answer... you just pass them in as a normal prop.

Comment: Ahh ok, thanks!  Wouldn't that still error out since `{this}` would be undefined within the `map` function?

Comment: You're absolutely right! I was just showing the normal approach... it would need to be tweeked to fit your specific line. All you need to do is assign `this` to a var right before the map (`var self = this`) and then use `self` within the map.

Comment: Doh!  Thanks lol.  Now I need to work on getting it updating again :)  Thanks again. Hopefully I can figure it out from here.

Comment: One more question.  I've noticed now that when doing the incrementing or decrementing it is updating all of them (list of 4) instead of the individual ones even though we are using this.

Comment: They might be all sharing the same state? it should be Product specific (i'd imagine).

Comment: Hmm yea I guess they all the share the same state but didn't previously.  Well it is I suppose depending on how you look at it.  Different levels of memberships but all tied to the specific Product.  I'll do some more researching and figure out how to split this up.  Thanks again!

Comment: Best luck -- feel free to start a new question if you can't figure it out.

Comment: @Quann feel free to open a new question -- this is a basic React functionality so if it didn't work there's probably some other things going on.